# unable to fix the type conversion issue from varchar to int on this query, I wrote

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help to fix a type conversion issue that is bugging me for few hours on the sp I wrote. I want to split up bill number like this '12/SH/IFCR/7' and get the last int value and store it separately

Eg. `'12/SH/IFCR/7'` --> `12/SH/IFCR/` and 7

Note: `12/SH/IFCR/` is prefix which stays the same but the last number changes

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spGenerateCreditInvoiceForApi 
        @ShopId as int,
        @TransId as int
        --@CompanyId as int
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        declare @CompanyId as int
        declare @Prefix as varchar(50)
        declare @ProformaId as int
        declare @MaxId as int
        declare @FinId as int
        declare @InvoiceNo as varchar(150)

        set @CompanyId=(select CompanyID from aShops where ShopID=@ShopId)

        set @FinId=(Select financialid from afinancialyear where  Curfinancialyear = 1 and companyid = @CompanyId)

        set @Prefix=(SELECT  Prefix FROM aPrefix WHERE InterfaceID = 1504 and ShopId=@ShopId and FinancialId = @FinId)

        set @ProformaId=(select ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT,REVERSE(LEFT((REVERSE(ihInvoiceNo)),(PATINDEX('%/%' ,(REVERSE (ihInvoiceNo))))-1)))),0)
         from LOsInvoiceHeader
         where ihInvoiceID= @TransId and ihShopID=@ShopId)

        --SET @intBillID = (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(poshBillid)=0 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(poshBillid)+1 END FROM losposheader WHERE poshShopID=@intShopId)

        set  @MaxId=(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(ihInvoiceNo)=0 THEN 1
         ELSE MAX(ihInvoiceNo)+1 END 
        from losinvoiceheader
        where ihShopId =@ShopId and ihfinancialid=@FinId and ihType='I')

        SET @InvoiceNo = (@Prefix+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@MaxId)) 

        --update LOsInvoiceHeader set ihInvoiceNo=@InvoiceNo, ihProformaID=@ProformaId where ihInvoiceID=@TransId and ihShopID=@ShopId

        --print @InvoiceNo
    END
    GO
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGenerateCreditInvoiceForApi, Line 33
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12/SH/IFCR/7' to data type int.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the prefix stays the same, couldn't you just replace it with an empty string and use that result for easier logic? No need for all the reverse, left, patindex things. Would also make it easy to find what cannot be converted / doesn't follow the logic

Comment: prefix is auto generated yearly, so its length may change, which will cause issues in the future, that is why we're reversing ill number and picking up the int value before the '/' and I think that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank god I found the issue

I changed use of Max() to count() and added a convert method to the whole query

**Before**

```
set  @MaxId=(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(ihInvoiceNo)=0 THEN 1
         ELSE MAX(ihInvoiceNo)+1 END 
        from losinvoiceheader
        where ihShopId =@ShopId and ihfinancialid=@FinId and ihType='I')
```

**After**

```
set  @MaxId=CONVERT(INT,(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(ihInvoiceNo)=0 THEN 1
     ELSE CONVERT(INT,COUNT(ihInvoiceNo)+1) END 
    from losinvoiceheader
    where ihShopId =@ShopId and ihfinancialid=@FinId and ihType='I'))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
declare @bill varchar(50),
 @reversebill varchar(50),
  @reverseResult varchar(50)

select @bill = '12/SH/IFCR/73'
select @reversebill = REVERSE(@bill)
select @reverseResult = SUBSTRING(@reversebill,0,CHARINDEX('/',@reversebill))

select Reverse(@reverseResult)
```